# Emacs Key Binding Error

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, key-bindings

When I try to set the following binding:

`(global-set-key "\C-M-v" 'scroll-other-window-up)`

I get a "Key Sequence RET - v starts with a  non-prefix key RET"

What is that?

Answer (score 3):

The binding you have specified is "Control-M-v". Control-M is the key sequence for the non-printable character 'carriage return' and is equivalent to the RET key. The RET key is already bound so it is not available as a prefix key.

Did you intend the binding to be Control+Meta+v? That would be:

```
(global-set-key "\C-\M-v" 'scroll-other-window-up)
```

Answer (score 3):

The key string you used `"\C-M-v"` is getting translated as `C-m` - which is also the key <kbd>RET</kbd>.

I think the easiest way to do key bindings is to use the [`kbd` macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html).  When you do <kbd>C-h k</kbd> and see a string describing which key you just typed, you can cut/paste that into the argument for kbd:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-v") 'scroll-other-window-up)
```

Comment: I am trying this: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<down>") 'scroll-other-window-down)` but now when I hit Control-Meta-Arrow Down I get: ESC <down> is undefined. Why is that?

Comment: @Nayefc The way to specify that is "C-M-down".  You can find that out by doing `C-h k` and the keystroke you want, and Emacs will show you that the down doesn't have the angle brackets.

Comment: It says: `ESC <down> (translated from ESC M-O B) is undefined`. So it isn't even recognizing the `CTRL` button when I hit `Ctrl-Meta-down`

Comment: Are you running Emacs in a terminal? Most terminals will present issues when it comes to keybindings, and if Emacs isn't seeing a keystroke, the majority of the time it is because the terminal did not send it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-v") 'scroll-other-window-up)
```

but be aware that standard emacs does not have a *scroll-other-window-up* function!

Comment: I am trying this: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<down>") 'scroll-other-window-down)` but now when I hit Control-Meta-Arrow Down I get: ESC <down> is undefined. Why is that? I've been battling with this for about 3 hours now! Emacs key bindings are absolutely ridiculous.